# How to set the values in application.properties to connect my document db from the credentials which I got from secrets manager?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aws-documentdb

I'm new to Spring boot, in my project database connection configs are in the application.properties file. How can I set up mongodb.uri, database, username values from the code because I get the credential from AWS Secrets manager and I wanted to connect my document db from those credentials.
Thanks in advance.

Application.properties file

```
spring.aws.secretsmanager.secretName=Beacon/DevDB
spring.data.mongodb.database=amitdb
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://***:***@****.cluster-cpq4eks8dl1q.us-east 1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/dashboardreplicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.